# Change one part of the name of more than 1000 files

Tags: shell-script, files, rename

I have a set of about more than 1000 files that their names are such as `IR.ANJ.G1.E.20060102.185428.mseed` with `G1` in common.

I am going to change `G1` in all files to `SH`.

For example, `IR.ANJ.G1.E.20060102.185428.mseed` change to `IR.ANJ.SH.E.20060102.185428.mseed` and continuing for all files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `rename`.

```
rename -nv 's/\.G1\./\.SH\./' *.G1.*
```

`-n` is used to dry run, once you see what being renaming and if that's correct, remove `n` option to have actual rename.

Comment: Sorry, how about the following: "IR.KHGB..BHN.20110506.152700.mseed" change to "IR.KHGB.SHN.20110506.152700.mseed". Note we have also 2 points before BH that changed to one point

Comment: try `rename -nv 's/\.\.BHN\./\.SHN\./' *..BHN.*`

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` or any other shell that understands the pattern substitution `${parameter/pattern/string}`:

```
for name in ./*.G1.*; do
    echo mv "$name" "${name/.G1./.SH.}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` after running once with it (to check that it's doing the right thing).